# Nykthos, Shrine to Nyx vs Contamination

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In my current meta one of the players likes to play [Contamination](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?name=Contamination).  If I have a [Nykthos, Shrine to Nyx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373713) in play, and my opponent has a Contamination, would it be possible to produce non-black mana with the Nykthos, Shrine to Nyx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**With Contamination on the battlefield, you cannot get anything other than a single black mana from activating Nykthos's abilities.**

The current wording of Contamination's second ability says:

> If a land is tapped for mana, it produces {B} instead of any other type and amount.

This is a replacement effect (indicated by the word "instead") that modifies the effect of tapping a land for mana. [Rules section 106](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Mana) has the following relevant rules about tapping for mana:

> - **106.12.** To “tap [a permanent] for mana” is to activate a mana ability of that permanent that includes the {T} symbol in its activation cost. See rule 605, “Mana Abilities.”
> - **106.12b** A replacement effect that applies if a permanent “is tapped for mana” or tapped for mana of a specific type and/or amount modifies the mana production event while such an ability is resolving and producing mana or the specified type and/or amount of mana.

Both of Nykthos's abilities have the {T} (tap) symbol in the cost, so both are modified by Contamination's ability. So, if you activate either one, no matter what mana you would normally get, you get exactly one black mana instead.